# Using kubernetes ingress to expose multiple services, without exposing the services with NodePort

Tags: kubernetes

I'm trying to set up a cluster like this:

```
+--------------+  +---------------+
|              |  |               |
| Express API  |  | Front End     |
|              |  | Static Assets |
|              |  |               |
+------+-------+  +--------+------+
       ^                   ^
       |                   |
       |                   |
+------+-------------------+------+
|  /api/..                 /      |
|            Ingress              |
+--------------+------------------+
               ^
               +
            Internet
```

For now I'm doing this on Minikube.

I've looked at these two guides:

https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/

https://medium.com/@Oskarr3/setting-up-ingress-on-minikube-6ae825e98f82

In the second guide - he exposes his deployments with NodePort services, and then configures his ingress to use those services.

This also means - that those services can be just accessed directly via IP address.

However, my understanding is that that's not necessary  - you can just declare an unexposed service, and let ingress expose them. ([similar to how they've done it in this official documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/connecting-frontend-backend/)).

ie:

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: template-frontend-service
  labels:
    app: template
spec:
  selector:
    app: template
    type: frontend
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: 80

kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: template-api-service
  labels:
    app: template
spec:
  selector:
    app: template
    type: api
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: 3001
```

But this is where I'm running in to an issue:

Ingress:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: template-ingress
  labels:
    app: template
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec:
  backend:
    serviceName: default-http-backend
    servicePort: 80
  rules:
    - host: template.example.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            backend:
              serviceName: template-frontend-service
              servicePort: 80
          - path: /api
            backend:
              serviceName: template-api-service
              servicePort: 80
```

I get:

> 503 Service Temporarily Unavailable 
>   nginx/1.13.12

On the other hand, if I just expose my deployments directly with:

```
kubectl expose deploy template-api --type=NodePort
kubectl expose deploy template-frontend --type=NodePort
```

(this will give me two services `template-api` and `template-frontend`)

then this configuration will work:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: template-ingress
  labels:
    app: template
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec:
  backend:
    serviceName: default-http-backend
    servicePort: 80
  rules:
    - host: template.example.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            backend:
              serviceName: template-frontend
              servicePort: 80
          - path: /api
            backend:
              serviceName: template-api
              servicePort: 80
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Could you share your ingress-controller configuration related to backends  "/" and "/api"  using command <kubectl exec -it nginx-ingress-controller-RANDOMHASH -n kube-system cat /etc/nginx/nginx.conf > (set the correct namespace and replace controller name with actual name of the ingress controller in your cluster)?

Answer (score 4):

> 503 Service Temporarily Unavailable

I'm getting this error in two cases:

- service mentioned in ingress does not exist
- service does exist, but there is no pod matched by service selector.

Nginx Ingress controller is able to access service without necessity to specifying `type=NodePort` for a service.
I've tested a configuration that is quite close to yours and it works fine with the service `type=ClusterIP`.
Miniube version is v0.30.0 (ingress addon enabled)

Ingress service is configured as NodePort because we have to access it from host machine:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: nginx-ingress
  namespace: kube-system
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: nginx-ingress-controller
    app.kubernetes.io/part-of: kube-system
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
    - name: http
      port: 80
      targetPort: 80
      protocol: TCP
    - name: https
      port: 443
      targetPort: 443
      protocol: TCP
  selector:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: nginx-ingress-controller
    app.kubernetes.io/part-of: kube-system
```

Here is the log of experiment:
I've created two deployments for frontend and api and checked if it's running:

```
$ kubectl run template-frontend --image=hashicorp/http-echo --labels=app=template,type=frontend -- -listen=:80 -text="Frontend"
$ kubectl run template-api --image=hashicorp/http-echo --labels=app=template,type=api -- -listen=:80 -text="API"
$ kubectl get pods -o wide
```

I've exposed them via ClusterIP service and checked their addresses:

```
$ kubectl expose deployment template-frontend --port=80
$ kubectl expose deployment template-api --port=80
$ kubectl get svc -o wide
```

I've checked accessibility of pods via services using their ClusterIPs:

```
$ kubectl run ubuntu --rm -it --image ubuntu --restart=Never --command -- bash -c 'apt-get update && apt-get -y install curl less net-tools && bash'

root@ubuntu:/# curl http://10.96.101.51
API
root@ubuntu:/# curl http://10.107.165.156
Frontend
```

I've applied ingress.yaml file to the cluster:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: template-ingress
  labels:
    app: template
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec:
  backend:
    serviceName: default-http-backend
    servicePort: 80
  rules:
    - host: template.example.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            backend:
              serviceName: template-frontend
              servicePort: 80
          - path: /api
            backend:
              serviceName: template-api
              servicePort: 80
```

Now I need to check the IP address of minikube node:

```
$ minikube ip
192.168.99.100
```

and the service node port:

```
$ kubectl get svc --all-namespaces | grep ingress
```

Usualy the port number in the range of 30000 and 33000

```
kube-system   nginx-ingress          NodePort    10.99.220.242    <none>        80:32462/TCP,443:32318/TCP   1h        app.kubernetes.io/name=nginx-ingress-controller,app.kubernetes.io/part-of=kube-system
```

Finally I check if the pods are able to serve requests via ingress:

```
$ curl -H "Host:template.example.com" http://192.168.99.100:32462/api/
API
$ curl -H "Host:template.example.com" http://192.168.99.100:32462/
Frontend
```

Comment: How about when the page is redirected to itself endlessly and a message appears saying "If you are not redirected automatically, follow this link"?

Comment: Please create a new stack question with all related env details and YAMLs

Comment: Question created: https://serverfault.com/questions/1076730/keycloak-infinite-redirection-with-ingress. Thanks in advance